# Good review but 1 star on Play Store/App Store. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: app-store-connect, google-developers-console

I have a problem as stated in the title. Sometimes in the Play Store, users make comments saying that they like our application. (Good, super, I like it) But they give 1 star either intentionally or accidentally. I tried to give them all kinds of answers. I offered a free trial to fix the comment. I said, 'I think you gave the wrong star, please correct it'. I made such comments, but no one corrected it. Users who make such comments are usually from the same country. 3-4 similar countries.

What do those of you who encounter this problem do? Any suggestion?

Thank you. Healthy days.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask for advice about this kind of problem. I think you best talk to Google about this.

Comment: There are only two possibilities: 1. (as you already do) post an answer to the review and ask the person for an update of the review/rating or 2. report an inappropriate review to Apple/Google (see their docs on how to do that). But I honestly doubt they will remove such reviews/ratings

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same exact thing from Countries that have languages that are written Right-to-Left.

I think this is a user experience problem in Google play with these languages, if the user quickly adds the review then it he/she could accidently put 1 start instead of 5 stars.

Unfortunately you can not do anything about it.